# was not expecting to hear from you ANYMORE

Tags: word-choice

> I am surprised to receive your answer, I was not expecting to hear from you **anymore**

Is anymore a good choice or shall I write:

> I was not expecting to hear from you

The context is because the person took a very long time to answer.

Comment: Except in US English, 'anymore' meaning 'any longer' is likely to be considered an error and corrected to 'any more' (two words).

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you're trying to communicate. If you were simply not expecting to hear from the person *at this time*, then "I was not expecting to hear from you" is fine.

On the other hand, if you have previously received a message from the other person, but you were expecting to *never again* hear from them, then "I was not expecting to hear from you anymore" works, but would probably be more commonly phrased as "I was not expecting to hear from you again."